Granular regression with repeating dependent variable within group
I am estimating a standard OLS regression model where the unit of observation is inventor-firm-year level. The dependent variable I am interested in is patent count (a measure of inventor productivity), but this variable is perfectly correlated within team-firm cluster (i.e., all inventors on the same team at the same firm will have the same observation). My questions:

Does this fact violate standard OLS assumptions of the error structure? My hunch is that it does since that would mean that independent variables and the error term must be mechanically correlated. See discussion here.
Can clustering standard errors at the firm level (or include additional fixed effects) fix this problem?

For reference, an example of papers that estimate inventor level regressions is Baghai, Silva, and Ye (2024).
